# Not able to check an empty string

Tags: c++

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,l;
    char a[22];
    a[0]='0';
    for(t=1;t<=20;t++)
    {
        l=1;
        scanf("%s",a+1);

        if(strlen(a)>1)
            l=strlen(a);
        printf("%d\n",l-1);
    }
     return 0;
}
```

When I am inputting any string with length >= 1 then I get the correct answer for the length of string but when just use the keystroke enter or space then it does not print 0. Since the string is empty(containing only zero) it should print 0(l-1=0) because if condition gets false.

Comment: The `%s` format of `scanf` can't read an empty string. Instead, it will wait until you eventually enter a non-empty string (or non-whitespace string, rather). `scanf` also doesn't care about newlines; it just treats them as space. That property doesn't make it an intuitive input mechanism for input from the console. Use `fgets` to read lines.

Comment: And since you marked the question C++ also, I suggest using the type-safe C++ iostreams instead. Note that to get high performance, you may need to disable sync between C and C++-style input/output mechanisms. Google it and you find out how.

Comment: Why are you using C strings and I/O functions in a C++ program?

Comment: How is a string containing the digit zero empty?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `fgets`. This answer is for C.

Change

```
scanf("%s",a+1);
```

to

```
fgets (a, sizeof (a), stdin);
```

Comment: I just figured out a reason for the downvotes. This is tagged `C++` and this is for `C`. But do not downvote this as the question was originally tagged both `C` and `C++`, thus this answer for `C`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I came here from your meta question (on the downvoting) and was curious to see your answers. I cannot speak for the downvoters, but I'd assume that you could get upvotes if your answers would be explaining a bit more (why use `fgets`, limitations of `sizeof` in your solution, issues with `scanf`).